# Force maxima to think square root is imaginary

Tags: constraints, maxima

I wanted to see how an elliptic trajectory of a dynamical system gets rotated with different system parameters.  So I tried

```
assume(c<0);
assume(b>0);
assume(b*c<-a^2);
A:matrix([a,b],[c,-a]);
eigenvalues(A);
```

I get the result

```
[[-sqrt(b*c+a^2),sqrt(b*c+a^2)],[1,1]]
```

However, I want

```
[[-%i*sqrt(a^2+b*c),%i*sqrt(a^2+b*c)],[1,1]]
```

It appears that maxima did not use my assumption. How can I make it use such an assumption or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Maxima's assumption capability is not very strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a simplification rule:

```
(%i1) display2d: false $
(%i2) assume(c<0, b>0, b*c<-a^2) $
(%i3) A:matrix([a,b],[c,-a]) $
(%i4) negp(e):= is(sign(e)='neg) $
(%i5) matchdeclare(NN, negp)     $
(%i6) tellsimpafter(sqrt(NN), -%i*sqrt(-NN)) $
(%i7) eigenvalues(A);
(%o7) [[%i*sqrt((-b*c)-a^2),-%i*sqrt((-b*c)-a^2)],[1,1]]
```